# Why is this method in a class is not getting extended to the next class, instead I see - [Function (anonymous)] in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-class

register() works fine with the Person class and I do see the return statement when I console.log it after the Person class

Later on I am extending it to my Employee class but when I console.log it there, I see - [Function (anonymous)] instead of the return statement which I have set

here is the code :

```
interface PersonInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  register(): string;
}

// Classes
class Person implements PersonInterface {
  id: number; 
  name: string;

  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  register() {
    return `${this.name} is now registered`;
  }
}

const mike = new Person(2, "Mike Jordan");

// console.log(mike.register()); - I get 'Mike Jordan is now registered'
   
class Employee extends Person {
  position: string;

  constructor(id: number, name: string, position: string) {
    super(id, name);
    this.position = position;
  }
}

const emp = new Employee(3, "Shawn", "Developer");

console.log(emp.register);
```

and this is what I see in the terminal for that console.log

```
[Function (anonymous)]
```

It seems like the method is not extended properly.
How can I resolve this - the goal is to see the return statement just the same way that it works within the Person class

Comment: What needs resolving? What do you expect to see? `register` is a function. It logs a function.

Comment: did you not see the return statement ?

Comment: If you want to call the method you need to add parenthesis, console.log( emp.register() );

Comment: There's a difference between `console.log(mike.register());` and `console.log(mike.register);`. Same for the inherited method on `emp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you are console logging

```
console.log(emp.register);
```

which returns:

```
register() {
    return `${this.name} is now registered`;
}
```

aka a function, if you add parenthesis

```
console.log(emp.register());
```

it will return

```
"Shawn is now registered"
```